# how to sort using dates in comma separated value php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, for-loop, codeigniter

i have a list of comma separated values, i am trying to display them according to the dates in ascending order, i did the following code:

```html
 <?php
$s1=explode(',',$val['ddate']);
$s2=explode(',',$val['details']);
$s3=explode(',',$val['type']);
$s4=explode(',',$val['ref']);
$s5=explode(',',$val['status']);
 sort($s1);
$ii=1;
for($i=0;$i<count($s1);$i++){
      ?>
      <tr >
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $s1[$i];?></th>

        <td><?php echo $s3[$i];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $s2[$i];?></td>

        <td> <?php echo $s5[$i];?></td>

      </tr>
<?php $ii++; } ?>
```

here, when i use that sort function, only the dates are getting sorted correctly, other fields are comming wrong, i mean the respective values related to that date is not coming, can anyone please tell me how to sort this correctly, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Php you can use **[array_multisort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)** function.

The **array_multisort()** function returns a sorted array. You can assign one or more arrays. The function sorts the first array, and the other arrays follow, then, if two or more values are the same, it sorts the next array, and so on.

Following is an example to implement **array_multisort()** function:

```
<?php
$ar1 = array(10, 100, 100, 0);
$ar2 = array(1, 3, 2, 4);
$ar3 = array(5, 7, 1, 8);
array_multisort($ar1, $ar2, $ar3);



foreach ($ar1 as $key => $val) {
    echo "ar[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "<br>";
}
echo '<br>';
foreach ($ar2 as $key => $val) {
    echo "ar[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "<br>";
}
echo '<br>';
foreach ($ar3 as $key => $val) {
    echo "ar[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "<br>";
}
?>
```